# How to access different arrays of different types with a unique scoped enum?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have 2 structs (**ScreenN** and **ScreenR**) inheriting from a base struct (**Screen**). They just have POD data with no members.

```
struct Screen {
 int base {10};
};

struct ScreenN : public Screen {
 int spe_n {20};
};

struct ScreenR : public Screen {
 int spe_r {30};
};
```

A **Test** class containing 2 arrays of structs :

```
class Test {
    public:
        auto getScreen(const Bg s){};

    private:
        std::array<ScreenN, 2> n_;
        std::array<ScreenR, 2> r_;
};
```

And finally a scoped enum that will be used to access the various structs :

```
enum class Bg : unsigned char{
    n0,
    n1,
    r0,
    r1
};
```

My goal would be to access both arrays elements using the same scoped enum :

```
Test t;
const auto s = Bg::n0;
std::cout << t.getScreen(s).spe_n << std::endl;
std::cout << t.getScreen(Bg::n0).spe_n << std::endl;
std::cout << t.getScreen(Bg::r0).spe_r << std::endl;
```

Given that I know exactly which enum entry links to which array element :

```
    Bg::n0 -> n_[0]
    Bg::n1 -> n_[1]
    Bg::r0 -> r_[0]
    Bg::r1 -> r_[1]
```

I want to be able to access the derived structs data directly, even if they aren't of the same type, is there a way to achieve this ? (ie what's the best way to code `getScreen(const Bg s){}`)

I have tried :

- Templates -> only work at compile time, so `t.getScreen(Bg::n0).spe_n` works, but `t.getScreen(s).spe_n` doesn't.
- std::variant -> I haven't figured out how to return the value I want using std::visit
- inheritance -> works fine for functions, but I want to be able to access POD data too ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: C++ has static types. A function returns either `ScreenN` or a `ScreenR`. It cannot sometimes return a `ScreenN` and sometimes a `ScreenR` depending on what parameter you pass. If you are writing `t.getScreen(s).spe_n` it is statically known that `t.getScreen(s)` is `ScreenN`, and of you are writing `t.getScreen(s).spe_r` it is statically known that `t.getScreen(s)` is `ScreenR`. It doesn't make a lot of sense to try and make `t.getScreen(s)` having the same type on both cases. Just use two different functions, one returning `ScreenN` and one returning `ScreenR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is to have `getScreen` return a different type based on a runtime parameter (the enum)? Is that correct?

That's not how C++ works; it's a statically typed language. Each function has a single return type; and that type is determined at compile time.

Now, as to what you've tried:

- Templates - these stamp out multiple copies of runtines (in this case), each with their own (static) return type. But as you've found, you can't decide which one to call at runtime.
- `variant` - you could return a `variant<ScreenN, ScreenR>` from getScreen and let the caller figure out which one it is - but that pushes all the complexity back onto the caller.
- inheritance - you could wrap the arrays in a struct that inherits from a base, and return a pointer to base; but that has the same drawbacks as `variant` (i.e, it forces the caller to deal with the complexity).

Comment: Actually I'm using a single array in my code base, with a single struct having all the data inside ... my question was more about if it could be done, using maybe a less known technique, but as the answer is no I won't push the matter further. Thanks for your answer :)